# How to parse an attribute into a function in a class in python

Tags: python, class, attributes

I know i'm probably making a silly mistake but is there any reason that this isn't working? I am trying to delete a row in treeview by clicking on the row and then the delete button but for whatever reason the tv attribute isn't going into the function without an error.

```
class pageDeleteStaff(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Delete Staff", font = NORMAL_FONT)
        label.pack()

        tv = ttk.Treeview(self, height = 10, columns = ("StaffID, Forename, Surname, Wage, NIN, Account Name, Account Number, Contract Hours, Usercode, Passcode"))
        tv.pack()

        tv.heading("#0", text = "StaffID")
        tv.heading("#1", text = "Forename")
        tv.heading("#2", text = "Surname")
        tv.heading("#3", text = "Wage(£)")
        tv.heading("#4", text = "NIN")
        tv.heading("#5", text = "Account Name")
        tv.heading("#6", text = "Account Number")
        tv.heading("#7", text = "Contract Hours")
        tv.heading("#8", text = "Usercode")
        tv.heading("#9", text = "Passcode")

        tv.column("#0", width = 100)
        tv.column("#1", width = 170)
        tv.column("#2", width = 170)
        tv.column("#3", width = 150)
        tv.column("#4", width = 170)
        tv.column("#5", width = 200)
        tv.column("#6", width = 150)
        tv.column("#7", width = 150)
        tv.column("#8", width = 150)
        tv.column("#9", width = 150)
        conn = sqlite3.connect('subway.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM staff")
        staffData = c.fetchall()

        for row in staffData:
            tv.insert("", "end", text=row[0], values=row[1:])
            print(row)
        conn.close()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Delte", bg = 'grey', fg = 'black', font = SMALL_FONT, height = 2, width = 14,
                            command = self.deleteRow(controller))
        button4.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Menu", bg = 'grey', fg = 'black', font = SMALL_FONT, height = 2, width = 14,
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame(pageLabour))
        button4.pack()

    def deleteRow(self, controller):
        currentItem = self.tv.focus()
        item = tv.item(currentItem)
        if item.get("text") == "":
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "No member of staff selected!")
        else:
            staffID = int(item.get("text"))
            result = messagebox.askyesno("Are you sure?", "Are you sure you would like to delete?")
```

I'm getting an attribute error when calling tv into the function.

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTOnu.png)

Comment: Could you add the error you are getting to the question? Also, it seems you are using `ttk.Treeview` instead of `tk.Treeview`. I don't know whether that could be the problem or not.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\omaoi\Documents\Scoil\Ríomheolaíocht\Coursework\Code\v2.py", line 899, in <module>
    app = ApplicationController()
  File "C:\Users\omaoi\Documents\Scoil\Ríomheolaíocht\Coursework\Code\v2.py", line 36, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "C:\Users\omaoi\Documents\Scoil\Ríomheolaíocht\Coursework\Code\v2.py", line 613, in __init__
    command = self.deleteRow(controller))
AttributeError: 'pageDeleteStaff' object has no attribute 'deleteRow'